# How to find the smallest angle between two rectangles?

Tags: geometry, angle

I want to find the minimum angle between two rectangles.

If they are exactly paralell, the result should be 0. If they are orthogonal to oneanother it should be 0 too. I want values only between 0 and 45 degrees.

I came up with this formula, where I end up having results between 0 and 2025.
the two alphas are the angles of the longer edge of the rectangle.

[image: example]

Here is an example of the two extreme cases with the desired formula output of 0 and 45 degrees. The two alphas that I have are the main orientation of each rectangle. They can each range from 0-360°.

[image]

Comment: What are you meaning with "minimum angle of two rectangles" ? You have to explain it. As I have understood it, your first rectangle is defined by two vectors $L_1$ and $W_1$ (corresponding to Length and width) and $L_2$ and $W_2$ for the second one, and you want the minimum value among the 4 non oriented angles : $$angle(L_1,L_2), angle( L_1,W_2), angle(L_2,W_1), angle( W_1,W_2)$$ Right ?

Comment: yes, that is correct. apologies for my fuzzy wording.

Comment: I advise you, in order to simplify your issue to take $L_1,W_1$ as the classical basis vectors $i,j$.

Comment: Why are you squaring your result? I believe correct formula is something like this $\gamma = \left|\alpha_2-\alpha_1+90° \cdot\left\lfloor \dfrac{\alpha_1-\alpha_2+45°}{90°}\right\rfloor \right|$

Comment: Using arc cosine, this formula can be written like $\gamma=\frac14 \mathop{\rm \arccos} \cos(4(\alpha_1-\alpha_2))$.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I squared the results to make sure that negative and positive values result in the same. I could have taken the absolute too. The arc cosine function doesnt deliver the expected result. If i have two pairs of angles [0,90] and [0,0] i should receive both times the same result (preferably 0).